# Code style checking, specifically naming convention

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS tool that enforces the [ROS coding style](http://wiki.ros.org/CppStyleGuide) and in particular the naming conventions?

I am currently using [roslint](http://wiki.ros.org/roslint), but it doesn't seem to be checking the variable/class/method naming conventions.

I would like a tool that catches/fixes naming issues (those that don't adhere to a style).  Currently, I catch these issues at code review time, but it would be better if developers had a tool to catch/fix these mistakes themselves.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114476/code-style-checking,-specifically-naming-convention/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2014-01-02

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also likely not an answer you're hoping for, but for C++ there is [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html), which supports [customisable](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) style rulesets. Should be available on all platforms that Clang is available on.

By default it reformats any input files using the specified style, but it has options to output replacements as xml, which should allow for inclusion in a Jenkins style CI setup.

With some work, it looks like the `ROS_format.xml` from the wiki could be ported to ClangFormat format.

---

Edit:

> But will it catch/fix naming issues?

I don't think so (but I'm not sure). One of the few free tools that can do this seems to be [vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera/), which apparently is now on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Home). From what I understand this would need some serious work getting the ROS C++ style configured though (available ruleset [here](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Rules)).

---

Edit2: Codehaus SonarCube seems to have a vera++ plugin, which outputs checkstyle style XML reports, see [here](http://svn.codehaus.org/sonar-plugins/branches/cxx-plugin-ast/src/test/resources/org/sonar/plugins/cxx/vera++-reports/vera++-result-SAMPLE.xml) for a 'sample'.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2014-01-07**:
I'm not a stickler for spacing, just naming.  Since the ROS format is based on the google style and ClangFormat for google already exists, this might be OK.  But will it catch/fix naming issues?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any ROS tools that do that, but if you're using Python, try [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/). It's available as a Ubuntu/Debian package and can be configured to match the ROS naming conventions.

If you're using Eclipse to develop C++ code, check out the [ROS_format.xml](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Auto_Formatting) code style.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2014-01-07**:
I'm using ROS_format.xml, but it doesn't catch/fix naming mistakes.  Am I wrong?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-07**:
No, you're probably right. I haven't used it in a while, but now come to think of it of course it can only correct formatting, not variable names.